# why $e^{(x/(x - 1))}-1>0$ for all $x$ just to the left of $x = 0,$

Tags: limits

why $e^{(x/(x - 1))}-1>0$ for all $x$ just to the left of $x = 0$?
[Detailed process picture](https://iuimm2018.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/screenshot_20191124082217.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x<0,$

then $x-1<0,$

so $t=\dfrac x{x-1}>0,$

so $e^{t}>1,$

so $e^t-1>0$.

Comment: You're Right. Thank you.